# Can I build my .net-core application on a linux platform, then deploy to an azure web app

Tags: linux, azure, .net-core

I am building and deploying APIs to azure web apps, and want to setup a build pipeline for continuous delivery. The options for setting this up are very limited if using msbuild is a requirement. A lot of popular solutions are linux only, or docker based. 
  Is it possible to use a linux based build system to build an application (web Api), but then deploy it to an azure web app?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Create a web app with App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-how-to-create-a-web-app) on learn.microsoft.com?

Comment: Thanks, I understand if the target system is linux, then it should work ok. The linux option is in preview, and seems targeted mainly at php and node.js services. My question is, is it possible to deploy to a standard web app? Are the binaries produced by a build on linux the same as a build on windows ?